# Power set of $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For writing the power set of $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, do I have to consider $\emptyset$ as null set or as a member of the given set? If I consider $\emptyset$ as a member, then the power set is $\{\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}, \emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$. If my assumption is right, is there a better way to present the answer?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Sloan, that was exactly what I was looking for, but haven't found till now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written, $\emptyset$ is an element of the given set (and of course it is also a subset as it always is). The four elements you list are indeed the four subsets of the given two-element set, so you're right.